# Sitecore Admin Support Package generator Configuration

Tags: packages

In Sitecore Package generator, when I try to generate a package, for some reason, Sitecore is connecting to a different environment than production. We look for config files everywhere in Sitecore, but everything is ok. There is no dedicated config file for the package generator that we can update.

Anyone had this issue why Sitecore Package generator can point to the different environments and how can we configure that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when we have restored Master and Web database from other environments to the environment which I was having issues during generation of Sitecore Support Packages.

Basically, I've restored the Master and Web databases from Production to Staging, and I observed the same behavior as you are seeing now, which I believe is some garbage that needs to be cleaned out

In order to solve this issue, I had to execute the following SQL queries

**Core, Master and Web database**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[EventQueue];
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[PublishQueue];
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Properties];
```

And the following one in **Web database**, as it is helpful to have history in the Master database

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[History];
```

Comment: Thank you vinicius, yes that resolved the issue. As you mentioned the process that created issue on your environment is exactly what happened with us.